# ffmpeg: Infinite amount of filters/crossfading dynamic playlist

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, filtering, playlist, cross-fade

I want to use ffmpeg to play a dynamic playlist infinitely. The idea is, that an external command/script is executed to request the path to the next file (using the predicted start-time of the file as an argument) and continue playing files infinitely.

From the answer to "[Using FFMPEG to stream continuously videos files to a RTMP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647868/using-ffmpeg-to-stream-continuously-videos-files-to-a-rtmp-server)" i learned, that i need to write a custom demuxer, that is similar to the `concat` demuxer. The problem arises from the fact, that i want to **crossfade between the audio files** and from my understanding of the demuxer i would have to implement that functionality into the demuxer itself to be able to do it, because a demuxer can only produce one (or a finite number) audio output stream and you need two to use the [`acrossfade`-filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#acrossfade).

So i would have to set up the filter graph like this:

```
file1 --------------------------------*-->| cross | ---->more filters ---> Output
file2 -----------------*-->| cross |----->| fade  |
file3 --*-->| cross |----->| fade  |
      ... ->| fade  |
```

Using an infinite number of crossfade-filters.

Also i would really like to pre-filter(*, e.g. [`silenceremove`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove)) the audio files before cross-fading, which makes it even more complicated and the "implement everything in the demuxer"-approach even worse.

My current solution would be to implement a custom demuxer that alternates between two output streams and does the prefiltering internally as well as an input-alternating crossfade filter like this:

```
files -> | alternating |----->| alternating | ----> more filters--->
         |   demuxer*  |----->|  crossfade  |
```

The problem i see with this approach is that i would need to send multiple EOF-terminated files from the demuxer to the crossfade-filter and i don't know if that is even possible/allowed when using the standard ffmpeg functions like `ff_request_frame`.

Can you tell me if this approach is feasible or do you have a better solution to this problem or any idea that would make this easier?