# FFmpeg - How should I do to convince YouTube that it is receiving "endless" video stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, youtube-api, video-streaming

I'm using *FFmpeg* and *Youtube Live Streaming API* to live-stream videos to *YouTube*.

I made something generates video files continuously,
and I want to live-stream them to *YouTube* without any delay.

To feed them to *YouTube*'s RTMPT(rtmp://a.../live2/...) server,
I tried several things:

1. Just `while:; do ./ffmpeg ... rtmp://...; done`.
2. Piping

*YouTube* streamed them continuously, but not seamlessly.
It showed *Buffering icon* for about 20 seconds (as if a new YouTube stream gets created and starts to be fed), about 5 seconds before the currently showing video ends and the next video get showed.

```
| ...===============(BUFFERING)===== | ...===============(BUFFERING)===== | ...
```

It seems that *YouTube* just stops the stream when it detects the end of a video.
How should I do to convince YouTube that it is receiving "endless" video stream?

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer otherwise you're closing the connection.

Comment: @aergistal Is it possible to concatenate infinite, dynamic numbers of files? Or, do you mean [this _hack_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29050320/4510033)?

Comment: For dynamic you need to modify the concat demuxer or create your own.

Comment: @aergistal That would be a last resort. May I ask the reason why [the method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29050320/4510033) is inappropriate to achieve this?

Comment: Because it's not truly infinite and would require a large file. If big enough works for then you can just use a name convention and add the files in the concat list before they're created.