# Is it possible to set up ffmpeg as a repeater?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using [this PyLivestream library](https://github.com/scivision/PyLivestream) to stream files to youtube. the problem is that once it finishes each video the scren goes down for a second until the next video starts. because it's simply just creating ffmpeg command and running then directly in a subprocess for each media file.

Is it possible to configure an instance of ffmpeg that will always be streaming to the destination. It could just be a blank screen or an image. And it also has an input, so I can point PyLivestream to the repeater.

This way the repeater will create one long un-interupted stream experience, but I can still use PyLivestream to stream the individual files.

Comment: If you don't need any extra playlist management you could just concatenate the files directly with FFmpeg: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer

Comment: Do all your files have the same format, resolution and framerate? What OS are you using?

Comment: You can checkout if this thread can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647868/using-ffmpeg-to-stream-continuously-videos-files-to-a-rtmp-server

Comment: @Pyizza lead me to the solution but I can't mark a comment as an answer