# FFMPEG - infinite file video stream to RTMP server

Tags: linux, bash, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create an infinite video stream that I can push to a local **RTMP** server.

**I believe it's worth mentioning that I'm not very good with `ffmpeg`, I started using it some weeks ago.**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647868/using-ffmpeg-to-stream-continuously-videos-files-to-a-rtmp-server) is a similat question, but it doesn't fully answer what I need.

## What I tried

At my first attempt, I made a bash script that spawned a new `ffmpeg` instance for each video I was trying to stream. I noticed that that the few seconds that takes to spawn the new instance interrupts the stream.

After I noticed this problem, I decided to google some kind of queue system, and I found that `ffmpeg` has a **concat** function, that reads a file with a custom syntax and queues it.

So I made a script that lists the files in the directory where I store all my videos, modifies the output with `sed`, shuffles it (so the episodes are random), and then it redirects the output to a `playlist.txt`

```bash
find /mnt/episode/ -print | sed '/**.mp4/!d' | sed "s/^/file '/; s/$/'/" | shuf > playlist.txt
```

##### playlist.txt

###### example:

```
...
file '/mnt/episode/9/1.mp4'
file '/mnt/episode/8/4.mp4'
file '/mnt/episode/5/11.mp4'
file '/mnt/episode/7/15.mp4'
...
```

##### This creates 2 problems:

1. For some reason, while using the playlist/queue method, when it finishes a video... it takes like 30 seconds to switch to the next video.

```sh
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i playlist.txt -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

*(simplified command, using /dev/video0 device for testing purposes)*

`ffmpeg` does output something after the first video, but i'm not quite sure what it means.

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c8abc1b900] st: 1 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c8abc1b900] st: 1 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 0.
```

2. Once the playlist finishes, the stream is over. I could run the script that generates the playlist again, but that would mean that the stream cuts, which I don't want.

---

### What I want

I need a way to pick a random file, stream it normally via RTMP and once it finished, automatically pick another one **without interrupting the streaming**, and keep doing this until I decide to turn it off.

This is the directory format:

```
episodes
│
├── 1
│   ├── 1.mp4
│   ├── 2.mp4
│   ├── 3.mp4
│   ...
├── 2
│   ├── 1.mp4
│   ├── 2.mp4
│   ├── 3.mp4
│   ...
├── 3
│   ├── 1.mp4
│   ├── 2.mp4
│   ├── 3.mp4
│   ...
├── 4
│   ├── 1.mp4
│   ├── 2.mp4
│   ├── 3.mp4
│   ...
├── 5
│   ├── 1.mp4
│   ├── 2.mp4
│   ├── 3.mp4
│   ...
├── 6
│   ├── 1.mp4
│   ├── 2.mp4
│   ├── 3.mp4
│   ...
├── 7
│   ├── 1.mp4
│   ├── 2.mp4
│   ├── 3.mp4
│   ...
├── 8
│   ├── 1.mp4
│   ├── 2.mp4
│   ├── 3.mp4
│   ...
└── 9
    ├── 1.mp4
    ├── 2.mp4
    ├── 3.mp4
    ...
```

Gladly appreciate some help here. I tried to make the problem as clear as possible.

Thanks <3